# How to access all Recyclerview Viewholder class variable in another Adapter class in android studio

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, favorites

My question is how to unmark favorite icon/update button background in adapter after removing item from favorite activity in android studio

Answer (score 0):

If You Want to Add and Remove Favorite items then you need to create a `favorite value` in your database.

And get `favorite value` and check it in `onBindViewHolder` like

```
if(isFavorite){
//set favorite icon
    } else {
//set Unfavorite icon
}
```

After that, you no need to access variables.